# fitting hyperbolic and harmonic functions with curvefit

Tags: python, scipy

I have a problem working with curvefit function.
Here I have a code with two functions to work with. 
The first is an hyperbolic function.
The second is the same but with one parameter = 1.
My problem is that the result to fit the first function with curvefit works fine but with the second doesn´t.
I have a commercial program that generates correct solutions for both respectively. So it is possible to find a solution for the second function (a particular case of the first one as I mentioned above)
Is there someone that could give me an idea about what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks !

Here is the code to run:

```
def hypRegress(ptp,pir):

    xData = np.arange(len(ptp))
    yData = pir

    xData = np.array(xData, dtype=float)
    yData = np.array(yData, dtype= float)

    def funcHyp(x, qi, exp, di):
        return qi*(1+exp*di*x)**(-1/exp)

    def errfuncHyp(p):
        return funcHyp(xData, p[0], p[1], p[2]) - yData

    #print(xData.min(), xData.max())
    #print(yData.min(), yData.max())

    trialX = np.linspace(xData[0], xData[-1], 1000)



    # Fit an hyperbolic
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(funcHyp, xData, yData)
    print 'popt'
    #print(popt)
    yHYP = funcHyp(trialX, *popt)

    #optimization

    # initial values
    p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfuncHyp, popt,maxfev=10000)
    print p1

    aaaa = funcHyp(trialX, *p1)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(xData, yData, 'r+', label='Data', marker='o')
    plt.plot(trialX, yHYP, 'r-',ls='--', label="Hyp Fit")
    plt.plot(trialX, aaaa, 'y', label = 'Optimized')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show(block=False)
    return p1


def harRegress(ptp,pir):

    xData = np.arange(len(ptp))
    yData = pir

    xData = np.array(xData, dtype=float)
    yData = np.array(yData, dtype=float)

    def funcHar(x, qi, di):
        return qi*(1+di*x)**(-1)

    def errfuncHar(p):
        return funcHar(xData, p[0], p[1]) - yData

    #print(xData.min(), xData.max())
    #print(yData.min(), yData.max())

    trialX = np.linspace(xData[0], xData[-1], 1000)



    # Fit an harmonic
    popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(funcHar, xData, yData)
    print 'popt'
    print(popt)
    yHAR = funcHar(trialX, *popt)

    #optimization

    # initial values
    p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfuncHar, popt,maxfev=1000)
    print p1

    aaaa = funcHar(trialX, *p1)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(xData, yData, 'r+', label='Data', marker='o')
    plt.plot(trialX, yHAR, 'r-',ls='--', label="Har Fit")
    plt.plot(trialX, aaaa, 'y', label = 'Optimized')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show(block=False)
    return p1


ptp = ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
pir = ([150,85,90,50,45,60,60,40,40,30,28,30,38,30,26])

hypRegress(ptp,pir)
harRegress(ptp,pir)

input('pause')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a classic problem. The `curve_fit` algorithm starts from an initial guess for the arguments to be optimized, which, if not supplied, is simply all ones.

That means, when you call

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(funcHar, xData, yData)
```

the first attempt for the fitting routine will be to assume

```
funcHar(xData, qi=1, di=1)
```

If you haven't specified any of the other options, the fit will be poor, as evidenced by the large variances of the parameter estimates (check the diagonal of `pcov` and compare it to the actual values returned in `popt`).

In many cases, the situation is solved by *supplying an intelligent guess*. From your HAR-model, I gather that the values around `x==0` are the same in size as `qi`. So you could supply an initial guess of `p0 = (pir[0], 1)`, which will already lead to a satisfying solution. You could also call it with

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(funcHar, ptp, pir, p0=(0, 1))
```

which leads to the same result. So the problem is just that the algorithm finds a local minimum.

An alternative would've been to supply a different `factor`, the "parameter determining the initial step bound":

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(funcHar, ptp, pir, p0=(1, 1), factor=1)
```

In this case, even with the (default) initial guess of `p0=(1,1)`, it gives the same resulting fit.

Remember: fitting is an art, not a science. Often times, by analyzing the model you want to fit, you could already supply a good initial guess.

I can't speak for the algorithm used in the commercial program. If it is open-source (unlikely), you could have a look to see what they do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oliver ! Your answer was very clear and useful !